# Long audio file not playing

Tags: ios, audio, ibaction

Im trying to play a really long audio file in iOS (like 10 minutes long) and it doesn't want to play. I've gotten other files to work with this code just fine but this one just doesn't want to play.

Heres my code:

```
void SoundFinished (SystemSoundID snd, void* context) {
    NSLog(@"finished!");
    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(snd);
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(snd);
}

- (IBAction)lolol{
    NSURL* sndurl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"full video" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    SystemSoundID snd;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)sndurl, &snd);
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(snd, nil, nil, SoundFinished, nil);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(snd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is too long for **System Sound Services** to play it as mentioned in the docs -

> You can use System Sound Services to play short (30 seconds or shorter) sounds.

I suggest using an alternate way to play the file. Have a look at using **AVAudioPlayer** class to play the audio file.

Comment: Okay then... it looks like your resource file name contains white space. try renaming it, do a clean and then use avaudioplayer to try playing it.